# Change asynchronous post to normal MVC post which is synchronous

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a easy to solve problem with ajax post in our mvc project. There is a Model class of Customer object and one of it's property is CustomerPicture. After a form is filled by the customer correctly, he/she hits the Save button which is as usual. For posting image to server side we use a jquery plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for a special matter of our complex business strategy with other properties of Customer object. This plugin uses ajax post but we want to prevent this and want to make it a normal mvc post because of our bussines strategy.

```
data.submit();  // asynchronous post is triggered here by BlueImp jQuery Upload's default
```

I changed the default above code to below code but it didn't worked.

```
data.submit(function(){
    $('#frm_create_customer').submit();
});
```

As summaray of our problem is to change asynchronous post to normal server post which is synchronous. 
Hope you could do something works. Regards.

Comment: Why can you not use a regular file input and remove the data.submit() completely?

Answer (score 0):

As per jquery docs : The async option to $.ajax() defaults to true, indicating that code execution can continue after the request is made. Setting this option to false (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous) is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive.

You can make this option to false . 
You can also change the all async option for ajax to false then revert it to true after the call ...
You can use  $.ajaxSetup() also . This will also make all subsequent ajax calls to false ..

But I agree with previous answer that file uploading may not be done asynchronously .